# new Date().getTime() giving wrong results in relation to new Date().getHours()

Tags: javascript, date

So I'm doing an application that needs to get the current hour, minute, etc. but somehow the hour I'm getting is off by 3 hours. The minutes and seconds are alright, but when I try to get the hour it gives me 23, even though my system clock is at 20 hours.

so this is how I'm getting the current hour:

```
    var date = new Date();
    var hour = Math.floor((date.getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24); // 23
```

and the wierdest thing is, if I do `date.getHours()`, it gives me the correct answer, like so:

```
    var date = new Date();
    var hour = Math.floor((date.getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24); // 23
    date.getHours(); // 20, the correct answer
```

I find this to be very wierd. I guess I could just use `date.getHours()`, but I'm very intrigued by this behavior and wanted to understand why this is happening. How can the same date give me the correct hour when calling `date.getHours()`, but a different result when calculating the hour with the `date.getTime()` result? Can someone give me some insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getTime` returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, UTC. `getHours` returns the hour for the specified date, *according to local time.*

In other words, `getHours` is dependent on your local time zone, wereas `getTime` is not; see for example what happens if you use `getUTCHours`:

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log('getTime', Math.floor((date.getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24));
console.log('getHours', date.getHours());
console.log('getUTCHours', date.getUTCHours());
```

Comment: More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours

Comment: I don't know why I thought the getTime function would adjust itself with the date's time zone, but apparently it does not lol. Thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 2):

`getTime()` returns the number of ms since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z (UTC). Dividing it by the number of ms in a *typical* hour is an extremely naive approach.

For example...

```js
const d = new Date(2023, 1, 23, 0, 0, 0); // midnight 23rd Feb in local time
const typicalHoursSinceEpoch = d.getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60);
console.log("typical hours since epoch:", typicalHoursSinceEpoch);
console.log("calculated hour of day:", typicalHoursSinceEpoch % 24);
console.log("actual hour of day:", d.getHours());
```

Your calculation is correct in that it calculates the number of *typical* hours (3600000ms) since the epoch.

This is not the same thing as the current hour of the local time. The former is a unit of **elapsed time**. You may be able to adjust the calculation to account for your current timezone offset but it then ignores hours that are greater or less than 3600s and days that are greater or less than 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

According to mdn docs The getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch, which is defined as the midnight at the beginning of January 1, 1970, UTC.

so if you need current hours, minutes and seconds I would suggest to use this.

```
const date = new Date();
const hour = date.getHours()
const minutes = date.getMinutes()
const seconds = date.getSeconds()

console.log(hour,minutes,seconds)
```